Why does overflow text not work in modal box?
I'm trying to do a modal by doing this:
<div className='transaction-modal'>
   <div className='transaction-forms'>
      Content of the box modal here
   </div>
</div>

And I did this CSS for it:
.transaction-modal {
    background-color: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.48);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;

    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.transaction-forms {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 40px;
    max-width: 611px;
    justify-content: stretch;
}


But when I tried to use a Lorem500 in the bottom of my modal box HTML, it overflows the box and the .transaction-forms doesn't create any white background.
Why does this happen? I think it has something to do about the display: flex inside the .transaction-modal, but I just can't figure out a solution for that.
The form modal:

Text overflowing the box modal:

I want the text to extend the modal box, which means it would create more white background and it doesn't overflow the box.

remove justify-content: stretch; - it does nothing there. Add height: fit-content to .transaction-forms

In transaction forms, add a max-height, and also give it an overflow-y: auto; to enable it to scroll content if it exceeds the height.

Set the height of the transaction-forms class to fit-content. Also, remove justify-content: stretch.

Oh, thanks, that worked! I also found out that setting the 'flex-direction' for 'column' it would solve the issue as well. Is there any specific reason for this? I mean, why the flex-direction row has this different behavior from the flex-direction column? Why in the case of the flex-direction row do I must specify the height of the div to 'fit-content'?

@jaromand shared same thing in comment.

@RodrigoDorneles it’s because of how the children are laid out. In flex-direction: row, the children are laid out horizontally, so we will have to set the height to fix the vertical alignment. It goes the other way as well. But these aren’t the only way to fix the issue. You can also use the overflow property to ‘break-word, and set the word-wrap property to ‘break-word’. It’s like centering a div, we have plenty of options, we just have to find the right one for our markup.

The issue is caused by the display: flex and align-items: stretch properties, which make the content overflow the modal container. To fix this, you can use flex-direction: column and set overflow-y: auto on the .transaction-forms element to ensure proper scrolling and background display.
.transaction-modal {
    background-color: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.48);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow-y: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.transaction-forms {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 40px;
    max-width: 611px;
    max-height: 80vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

This solution ensures the content inside the modal scrolls properly and that the background remains visible.
